# Image inside an anchor causes misalignment

Tags: html, css

Here's the style:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img,
ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr,
th, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none; list-style: none; }

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}       
li { 
    width: 30.3%; 
    margin: 10px 1% 10px 1%; 
    padding: 0.5%; 
    float: left; 
    background: #000; 
}
li img { width:100%; }
```

and here's the html:

```
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
```

If you try it yourself, there's a small number of pixels on the left side of the image and it's really pissing me off. I've already tried inline-block and it's still there.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post your code at http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see whats the problem

Comment: Shouldn't the anchor be inside the list item rather than outside it?

Comment: No need of `li` tag there? any reason for that?

Comment: can u show a screenshot of how u want the result to be

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A3mU7/ not really visible on the small screen, but if you look closely, there's a tiny gap on the left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this html markup

```
<a href=""><li><img src="/images/test.png" /></li></a>
```

With this

```
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
```

and apply `display: block;` to your image and add `display: inline-block;` to your a

Comment: was gonna add text under the img, so I should try replacing the <li> with <a> instead..

Comment: You can add text by replacing also.

Comment: so, post your html in jsfiddle

Comment: actually, it did solve it. I removed all the <li> and replaced it with the <a>. My bad, had some error on rewriting my code. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

your html structure should be

```
<ul>
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="/images/test.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

and add following to the css

```
li img { width:100%; display:block; }
```

hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/8GUUw/

```
li { width:30.3%; float:left; background:#000; }
    li img { width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try moving the `<li>` tags outside of the links...